# Calling secrets with the same name but from different environments in GitHub

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, github-actions, amazon-ecs

I am working on setting up a pipeline that requires to have different Access Key IDs, one for Dev and one for Prod, I am trying to call it from the secrets with:

```
- name: Configure AWS credentials
  uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
  with:
    aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
    aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
    aws-region: ${{ needs.setup.outputs.AWS_REGION }}
```

But it only seems to use the keys from one environment, what changes can I make to use different keys in different environments?
This is how my Environment variables look right now.
[image]

This is my complete yml file:

```
name: 'Manual - Build & Deploy - Enterprise'

on:
  push:
    branches-ignore:
      - '**'

  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      git-ref:
        description: Git Ref (Optional)
        default: develop
        required: false

      account:
        description: slb-dev, slb-prod
        default: slb-dev
        required: true

      environment:
        description: development (main, int, qs), production (v1_demo, v1_rosecity, demo)
        default: main
        required: false

      microservice:
        description: chroma, liquid, tenant, dashboard, lims, lims-simulator, client, logging, metrc
        default: chroma
        required: false

      builddir:
        description: MicroChromatographyService/MicroChromatographyService, MicroLiquidHandlingService/MicroLiquidHandlingService, MicroTenantService/MicroTenantService, MicroDashboardService/MicroDashboardService, LIMSIntegrationService/LIMSIntegrationService, LIMSSimulatorService/LIMSSimulatorService, IntegrationHubClientService/IntegrationHubClientService, PerkinElmer.LoggingService/PerkinElmer.LoggingService, MetRCReportService/MetRCReportService
        default: MicroChromatographyService/MicroChromatographyService
        required: false

jobs:
  setup:
    name: Setup ENV Variables
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment:
     name: dev
     url: https://dev.test.com
    steps:

    - name: Set Vars
      id: setvars
      run: |
          echo "::set-output name=APP_NAME::${{ github.event.inputs.microservice }}"
          echo "::set-output name=AWS_REGION::us-east-1"
          echo "::set-output name=SHA8::${{ github.sha }} | cut -c1-8)"
          echo "::set-output name=BUILD_DIR::${{ github.event.inputs.builddir }}"
          echo "::set-output name=ECR_REPOSITORY::${{ github.event.inputs.account }}-${{ github.event.inputs.environment }}-${{ github.event.inputs.microservice }}"
          echo "::set-output name=ECS_CLUSTER::${{ github.event.inputs.account }}-${{ github.event.inputs.environment }}"
          echo "::set-output name=ECS_SERVICE::${{ github.event.inputs.account }}-${{ github.event.inputs.environment }}-${{ github.event.inputs.microservice }}"
          echo "::set-output name=ECS_TASK_DEFINITION::${{ github.event.inputs.account }}-${{ github.event.inputs.environment }}-${{ github.event.inputs.microservice }}"
          echo "::set-output name=ECS_TASK_DEFINITION_FILE::task-definition-${{ github.event.inputs.microservice }}.json"
          echo "::set-output name=ECS_CONTAINER_NAME::${{ github.event.inputs.account }}-${{ github.event.inputs.environment }}-${{ github.event.inputs.microservice }}"

    outputs:
      APP_NAME: ${{ steps.setvars.outputs.APP_NAME }}
      AWS_REGION: ${{ steps.setvars.outputs.AWS_REGION }}
      SHA8: ${{ steps.setvars.outputs.SHA8 }}
      BUILD_DIR: ${{ steps.setvars.outputs.BUILD_DIR }}
      ECR_REPOSITORY: ${{ steps.setvars.outputs.ECR_REPOSITORY }}
      ECS_CLUSTER: ${{ steps.setvars.outputs.ECS_CLUSTER }}
      ECS_SERVICE: ${{ steps.setvars.outputs.ECS_SERVICE }}
      ECS_TASK_DEFINITION: ${{ steps.setvars.outputs.ECS_TASK_DEFINITION }}
      ECS_TASK_DEFINITION_FILE: ${{ steps.setvars.outputs.ECS_TASK_DEFINITION_FILE }}
      ECS_CONTAINER_NAME: ${{ steps.setvars.outputs.ECS_CONTAINER_NAME }}
      

  DeployDev:
    name: Deploy to Dev 
    needs: setup
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
     packages: write
     contents: write
     id-token: write
    environment: 
      name: dev
      url: 'http://dev.myapp.com'
    steps:
    - name: Set Environments
      run: |
        if [[ "${{github.event.inputs.account}}" == "slb-dev" ]]; then
          echo "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=${{ env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID_DEV }}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          echo "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=${{ env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY_DEV }}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
        fi

        if [[ "${{github.event.inputs.account}}" == "slb-prod" ]]; then
          echo "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=${{ env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID_PROD }}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          echo "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=${{ env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY_PROD }}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
        fi

    - name: Clone Repository (Current branch)
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
      if: github.event.inputs.git-ref == ''

    - name: Clone Repository (Custom Ref)
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
      if: github.event.inputs.git-ref != ''
      with:
        ref: ${{ github.event.inputs.git-ref }}

    - name: Configure AWS credentials
      uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
      with:
        aws-access-key-id: ${{ env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
        aws-secret-access-key: ${{ env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
        aws-region: ${{ needs.setup.outputs.AWS_REGION }}

    - name: Login to Amazon ECR
      id: login-ecr
      uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecr-login@v1

    - name: Build, tag, and push image to Amazon ECR
      id: build-image
      env:
        ECR_REGISTRY: ${{ steps.login-ecr.outputs.registry }}
        ECR_REPOSITORY: ${{ needs.setup.outputs.ECR_REPOSITORY }}
        IMAGE_TAG: ${{ github.sha }}
      run: |
        cd ${{ needs.setup.outputs.BUILD_DIR }}
        docker build -t $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG -t $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:latest .
        docker push $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG
        docker push $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:latest
        echo "::set-output name=image::$ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG"

    - name: Download task definition
      run: |
        aws ecs describe-task-definition --task-definition ${{ needs.setup.outputs.ECS_TASK_DEFINITION }} --query taskDefinition > ${{ needs.setup.outputs.ECS_TASK_DEFINITION_FILE }}

    - name: Fill in the new image ID in the Amazon ECS task definition
      id: task-def
      uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecs-render-task-definition@v1
      with:
        task-definition: ${{ needs.setup.outputs.ECS_TASK_DEFINITION_FILE }}
        container-name: ${{ needs.setup.outputs.ECS_CONTAINER_NAME }}
        image: ${{ steps.build-image.outputs.image }}

    - name: Deploy Amazon ECS task definition
      uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecs-deploy-task-definition@v1
      with:
        task-definition: ${{ steps.task-def.outputs.task-definition }}
        service: ${{ needs.setup.outputs.ECS_SERVICE }}
        cluster: ${{ needs.setup.outputs.ECS_CLUSTER }}
        wait-for-service-stability: true


  DeployProd:
    name: Deploy to Production 
    needs: [DeployDev]
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
     packages: write
     contents: write
     id-token: write
    environment: 
      name: Production
      url: 'http://www.myapp.com'
    steps:
    - name: Set Environments
      run: |
        if [[ "${{github.event.inputs.account}}" == "slb-dev" ]]; then
          echo "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=${{ env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID_DEV }}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          echo "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=${{ env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY_DEV }}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
        fi

        if [[ "${{github.event.inputs.account}}" == "slb-prod" ]]; then
          echo "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=${{ env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID_PROD }}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          echo "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=${{ env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY_PROD }}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
        fi

    - name: Clone Repository (Current branch)
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
      if: github.event.inputs.git-ref == ''

    - name: Clone Repository (Custom Ref)
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
      if: github.event.inputs.git-ref != ''
      with:
        ref: ${{ github.event.inputs.git-ref }}

    - name: Configure AWS credentials
      uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
      with:
        aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}         
        aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
        aws-region: ${{ needs.setup.outputs.AWS_REGION }}

    - name: Login to Amazon ECR
      id: login-ecr
      uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecr-login@v1

    - name: Build, tag, and push image to Amazon ECR
      id: build-image
      env:
        ECR_REGISTRY: ${{ steps.login-ecr.outputs.registry }}
        ECR_REPOSITORY: ${{ needs.setup.outputs.ECR_REPOSITORY }}
        IMAGE_TAG: ${{ github.sha }}
      run: |
        cd ${{ needs.setup.outputs.BUILD_DIR }}
        docker build -t $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG -t $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:latest .
        docker push $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG
        docker push $ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:latest
        echo "::set-output name=image::$ECR_REGISTRY/$ECR_REPOSITORY:$IMAGE_TAG"

    - name: Download task definition
      run: |
        aws ecs describe-task-definition --task-definition ${{ needs.setup.outputs.ECS_TASK_DEFINITION }} --query taskDefinition > ${{ needs.setup.outputs.ECS_TASK_DEFINITION_FILE }}

    - name: Fill in the new image ID in the Amazon ECS task definition
      id: task-def
      uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecs-render-task-definition@v1
      with:
        task-definition: ${{ needs.setup.outputs.ECS_TASK_DEFINITION_FILE }}
        container-name: ${{ needs.setup.outputs.ECS_CONTAINER_NAME }}
        image: ${{ steps.build-image.outputs.image }}

    - name: Deploy Amazon ECS task definition
      uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecs-deploy-task-definition@v1
      with:
        task-definition: ${{ steps.task-def.outputs.task-definition }}
        service: ${{ needs.setup.outputs.ECS_SERVICE }}
        cluster: ${{ needs.setup.outputs.ECS_CLUSTER }}
        wait-for-service-stability: true
```

Comment: I observed that for the **dev environment field name**, you are using `dev` and not `Dev`. As your repository environments are named `Dev` and `Production`, it could explains your issue (if the workflow in the `Production` env is working as expected).

Comment: Even i am working with a similar workaround why dont you split your yaml files in to two? one yml file would be called as dev.yml and other would be prod.yml
when a feature or push happens to dev/feature configure dev.yml to be run.
when Pull request or feature is merged on lets say main branch configure prod.yml to run.
this way you can modularize your GitHub action which makes it easy to edit too rather than combining into one 

The Key is to configure .yml to trigger for dev and main branch that is imp.
Let me know if you like this idea I would be happy to help you with yml configuration

Comment: Do you think that if I change the name of the Environment from dev to Dev, that it should be able to grab the secrets from the specific Environment? I am not sure if it will run on Production since we couldn't get through Dev in the first place, but I will check.

Comment: Thanks, @JatinMehrotra I think splitting the YAML files is actually a neat idea, I could definitely use some help, for setting that up.

Comment: Posted an answer which will help you to split your Github Actions based on stages, this way its gets way easy to manage complex action and per stage logic.
It should do the trick

Answer (score -1):

So this is **how i split my actions specifically for production and other stages** ( includes dev and other feature requests too). *The following GA also demonstrates how you can use aws actions with the current OIDC feature once you have configured everything for OIDC. ( ofcourse your logic for GA will be different)*

**For any commits, the key is that this action is triggered on any push on any branch except main.**.Here i am configuring local sls and running ITG test and then deployong to dev stage

```
name: For All commits

on:
  push:
    branches-ignore: [main]
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      id-token: write
      contents: read

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [16.x]
        # See supported Node.js release schedule at https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
          cache: 'npm'
          cache-dependency-path: ./backend-operations/package-lock.json
  
      - name: Configure AWS Credentials
        uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@master
        with:
          aws-region: ap-southeast-1
          role-to-assume: ${{secrets.ROLE_ARN}}
      - run: npm ci
        working-directory: ./backend-operations
      - name: Install Serverless Framework
        run: npm install -g serverless
      - name: Install dynamodb local using plugin
        run: |
          serverless plugin install --name serverless-dynamodb-local
          sls dynamodb install
        working-directory: ./backend-operations
      - name: Serverless Authentication
        run: sls config credentials --provider aws --key ${{ env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }} --secret ${{ env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
      - run: npm run build --if-present
        working-directory: ./backend-operations
      - name: Start local sls env
        run: npm run start-local-sls &
        working-directory: ./backend-operations
      - name: Run Integration Tests
        run: |
          sleep 30
          npm run test-itg
        working-directory: ./backend-operations
      - name: Deploy to AWS
        run: serverless deploy --stage dev --verbose
        working-directory: './backend-operations'
```

**For production, here key is that this GA will be triggered on push only on main branch in your case you need to replicate one for main branch and one for dev branch**

```
name: Production-Deployment

on:
  push:
    branches: [main]
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      id-token: write
      contents: read

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [16.x]
        # See supported Node.js release schedule at https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
          cache: 'npm'
          cache-dependency-path: ./backend-operations/package-lock.json
 
      - name: Configure AWS Credentials
        uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@master
        with:
          aws-region: ap-southeast-1
          role-to-assume: ${{secrets.ROLE_ARN}}
      - run: npm ci
        working-directory: ./backend-operations
      - name: Install Serverless Framework
        run: npm install -g serverless
      - name: Serverless Authentication
        run: sls config credentials --provider aws --key ${{ env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }} --secret ${{ env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
      - name: Deploy to AWS
        run: serverless deploy --stage prod --verbose
        working-directory: './backend-operations'
```